# How to prove the uniqueness of a specific root?

Tags: calculus, integration, functional-analysis, functions, roots

Let us define: $$F(x):=\int_0^Tf(t)\cos(x\,t)dt-\frac{\sin(T_0\,x)}{T_0\,x}$$

where:

1). $0<T_0<T \in\mathbb{R}^+$ are both positive real constants, and

2). $0\leqslant f(x)\in C^{\infty}$ is monotonically decreasing in $[0,T]$;

Suppose:

$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}F(x)=0,\quad\text{and  } \exists\; x_0\in(0,\dfrac{\pi}{2T})\text{ such that}:F(x_0)=0.$

**Prove:**

$x_0$ is the unique root of $F(x)=0 $ in $(0,\dfrac{\pi}{2T})$;

or **equivalently**:

$F(x)>0,\;\forall\, x_0<x<\dfrac{\pi}{2T},$ and  $F(x)<0,\;\forall\; 0<x<x_0$

or is there **any counter example?**